# Toyota corolla 2009 engine noise type rattling ticking

Tags: engine, toyota, noise, corolla

toyota corolla 2009 engine noise 
Here is the the [video](https://youtu.be/L4MNZKCyVsk) I started after 30 days. engine oil level is one inch less than upper mark and water level is ok. also it initially when I started this car there was no noise. after few miles it starts giving me this noise. I can't classify this sound as ticking or rattle. it remains there as i change gears and on speed. Any guess or help is welcome.

Comment: Does the sound stays after driving a while also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the video, this sounds like a rod knock. Usually, the sound is the death knell of the engine. The only way to remedy is to completely rebuild the engine or engine replacement.

A rod knock usually occurs because the bearing clearances between the rod journal on the crankshaft and the bearing are too broad, which causes metal to metal contact between the two parts. Usually oil flow keeps these two parts separate. Continued running of the engine could result in further damage to the engine.

**EDIT:** [Explanation of ***What is a Rod Knock?***](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/21056/4152)

Comment: your answer is bad sign for my car. but accepting as looking very close :(

Answer (score 0):

IF you've been changing your oil and filter regularly, and NOT revving carelessly. you may not have a rod knock. Try a can of STP in the oil- this will NOT fix anything! But if the noise diminishes that will indicate a clearance problem.
On mine it was the front alternator bearing. Dealer and major chain mech assured my wife that replacing all the coils and injectors- 'cause they kinda go out together- would let her drive in peace and harmony for an other decade or two. I used my harbor freight stethoscope and traced the ticking. Huuge amounts of money for coils and injectors (plus a week or two) would not have fixed the problem- a rebuilt alternator and a Saturday did.